# Setting mouse cursor with a delay from another thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, mouse-cursor

I have some work to do in my main thread that sometimes last longer than a few seconds. I want to change the mouse cursor to a busy state (hourglass, over the whole main form) when that happens. But this must be done with a delay (say 250 ms), because most of the time the work is shorter and changing the cursor too often is annoying. I cannot do this from the main thread because it is obviously busy doing something else. So I thought to do it from another thread. But... surprise ! Setting `Screen.Cursor:= crHourGlass` from a thread does not work. I think the `Screen` object is meant to be accessed only from the main thread. I cannot synchronize anything with the main thread while it is busy... Any ideas on how to make it work ?

```
unit MouseCursor;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, Winapi.Windows;

type
  TMouseCursor = class(TThread)
  private type
    TCommand = (cmdSetBusy = $FB45BA57,cmdSetDone = $C75F1D29);
  private
    hResume: THandle;
    Command: TCommand;
    TimeOut: Cardinal;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure TerminatedSet; override;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor  Destroy; override;
    procedure Busy;
    procedure Done;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Controls;

const
  BusyDelay  = 250;

{ TMouseCursor }

constructor TMouseCursor.Create;
begin
 inherited Create(False);
 FreeOnTerminate:= True;
 hResume:= CreateEvent(nil, False, False, nil);
end;

destructor TMouseCursor.Destroy;
begin
 CloseHandle(hResume);
 inherited;
end;

procedure TMouseCursor.TerminatedSet;
begin
 Command:= cmdSetDone;
 inherited;
 SetEvent(hResume);
end;

procedure TMouseCursor.Busy;
begin
 Command:= cmdSetBusy;
 SetEvent(hResume);
end;

procedure TMouseCursor.Done;
begin
 Command:= cmdSetDone;
 SetEvent(hResume);
end;

procedure TMouseCursor.Execute;
var WaitRes: Cardinal;
begin
 TimeOut:= INFINITE;
 repeat
  WaitRes:= WaitForSingleObject(hResume, TimeOut);
  case WaitRes of
   WAIT_TIMEOUT : begin Screen.Cursor:= crHourGlass; TimeOut:= INFINITE; end;
   WAIT_OBJECT_0: case Command of
     cmdSetBusy: TimeOut:= BusyDelay;
     cmdSetDone: begin Screen.Cursor:= crDefault; TimeOut:= INFINITE; end;
   end;
  end;
 until Terminated;
end;

end.
```

Comment: You don't have to synchronize the whole thread, only the little part changing the mouse cursor.

Comment: I've already done that too, but it doesn't work. The cursor does not change until the main thread becomes available.

Comment: Please, make it right and do as @Roy suggests. Accessing the VCL from a thread is wrong. All work that can last longer  than a blink of an eye should be put into a thread.

Comment: @LURD who is Roy?

Comment: @RobLambden, My bad, apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to set the cursor using the thread that created the window.  I would suggest changing your design and putting the work being done by the main thread into a worker thread which can be monitored by the main thread (perhaps using a timer or by the worker thread issuing `Synchronize` calls).  Your main thread should not abandon the message loop that keeps the program running and responsive.  So in general your main thread should be continuously listening for and handing the system messages that are sent to it.  If any work *may* take some time put it into a worker thread.

For the `Synchronise` method to work the main thread has to be idle - the waiting `Synchronise` is picked up in the message loop.

Comment: You are right, but it's not really worth making a thread just for a 2-3 seconds work, and that occasionally. But I will think about it...

Comment: I take your point, but you had decided that it was worth making a thread to handle the cursor updates?  I'm not sure I understand why one is worth it and the other isn't ...

Comment: Because the one that handle the cursor updates would have been active for the whole app lifetime... The worker I have to create it every time.

Comment: Have you considered anonymous threads?  It shouldn't be much harder than using the code you have already written...

Comment: Nice answer +1.